# SQL To Include or Exclude based on parameter

Tags: sql-server

How would I write an SQL statement to return Customer Information either between a given range or excluding that given range?

This will be in a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008.

```
declare @CustomerTypeBegin int;
declare @CustomerTypeEnd int;
declare @CustomerTypeInclusive bit;

set @CustomerTypeBegin=2;
set @CustomerTypeEnd=4;
set @CustomerTypeInclusive=1;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TmpCustType (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Code varchar(10),
    Name varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
WHERE
    CASE @CustomerTypeInclusive
    WHEN 1 THEN CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
    ELSE CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
    END;
```

SQL Server Management Studio only shows "incorrect syntax."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is not for control of flow, its for returning a value.

Stitch the conditions together with logic:

```
WHERE
    (@CustomerTypeInclusive = 1 AND CustomerTypeId BETWEEN CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
    OR
    (@CustomerTypeInclusive = 2 AND CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was going to mark your previous question as the answer, but then it vanished! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 
 (@CustomerTypeInclusive = 1 AND CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
OR 
 (@CustomerTypeInclusive = 0 AND CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an *expression* not a *statement*, so it cannot be used to control order of execution.

You can achieve required result using standard SQL predicates:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
WHERE (@CustomerTypeInclusive = 1 AND 
       CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
      OR
      (@CustomerTypeInclusive <> 1 AND 
       CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write 2 insert statements:

```
IF ( @CustomerTypeInclusive = 1)
    INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
    SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
    FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
    WHERE CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
ELSE
    INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
    SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
    FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
    WHERE CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
```

OR you rewrite your where clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
WHERE CASE WHEN CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd THEN 1 END = @CustomerTypeInclusive
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write what you want with a `case` expression. The key though is to recognize that a `case` expression always evaluates to a *value*.

```
-- option #1
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @CustomerTypeInclusive = 1
             AND CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd THEN 1
        ELSE @CustomerTypeInclusive = 0
             AND CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd THEN 1 
    END = 1;

-- option #2
WHERE
    CASE @CustomerTypeInclusive
        WHEN 1 THEN
            CASE
                WHEN CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
                THEN 1
            END
        WHEN 0 THEN
            CASE
                WHEN CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd
                THEN 1
            END
    END = 1;
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. So using a CASE would require two (2) CASE statements.

Comment: @jp2code You could pick either of the two. The second has nested expressions but I thought it might have mirrored your original thinking a little closer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was an answer, but he deleted it before I could thank him. Alex, I think, was his UserID:

```
DECLARE @TmpCustType AS TABLE (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Code varchar(10),
    Name varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @TmpCustType (Id, Code, Name)
SELECT CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeCode, CustomerTypeName
FROM [CustomerTypeLookup]
WHERE
    (@CustomerTypeInclusive=1 AND CustomerTypeId BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd) OR
    (@CustomerTypeInclusive=0 AND CustomerTypeId NOT BETWEEN @CustomerTypeBegin AND @CustomerTypeEnd);
```

He told me to remove the CASE.